# Frame/toolbar like separate activity on top of all other activities?

Tags: android, android-activity

Im making a music player/library app in wich I would like a frame/toolbar on top of all other activities as a header. This frame/toolbar will show information about the current playing track and have some controlls like play, next and stop etc. and be a separate selfsufficiennt activity. Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an [`ActivityGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html).  This is how `TabHost` is implemented.  So  your `ActivityGroup` would fill the whole window and implement the toolbar.  Then you could swap out `Activities` in the bottom part.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be exactly what im after.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I don't think that making a static top bar it's own activity in the life-cycle idea. However, what you can do is have every activity have the top bar and just re-create the bindings needed for each activity. It gives the idea that a section is static.

Now this breaks down if you start doing animations between the screens. Another solution is to just have a single activity and swap out the views. This allows for animations between screens be custom and only the parts that change need to create the connections they need. The trade off there is that you'll lose any kind of state saving and history that you gain by using an activity orientated approach.

I think you can do something like this on Honeycomb tablets as the fragments idea could be implemented like that but I've never explored it much.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The top bar will make timed http reqests and some more stuff so i thought it would be unnecessary to recreate the same stuff each time I change activity and having the bar dissapares and then reappear again with the same information (whith the activity change).

Comment: General rule of thought I use in Android is that if it's not doing anything UI oriented it belongs in a service. If your top bar is doing anything I would push it off to a service with a callback to update the top bar. That way the http requests are done in the service and your just relaying the information to the UI.